# In which regions of the world do graduate programs typically require a GRE score?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

I know that in most U.S. universities, most programs for graduate studies require a GRE score.

1- Are there any graduate programs in the U.S. which does not require this?

2- Is it required for graduate programs in Europe, Australia or other parts of the world?

Comment: A better question would probably be: "Does *any* university *at all* outside the US require a GRE score?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ETS, which develops and administers the GREs, [maintains a publicly available list](http://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/gre_aidi_fellowships.pdf) of all of the institutions that are officially licensed to receive GREs.
If you look through, you will notice that almost all of these institutions are in the United States.

Now, there are a bunch of other universities around the world that at least are willing to receive a GRE.  As noted in the other answers, however, the fact that an institution is willing to receive a GRE does not mean that it is required or even particularly helpful.  It is primarily a US test, and even within the US it is not used by many departments and given little weight (unless one does horribly) in many others.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the United States, I have not heard of any country and any topic requiring it.

Answer (score 2):

I've studied in Australia and the U.K., and I believe that no universities require GRE for graduate admission. I don't believe that GRE is required in continental Europe either, but there may be exceptions.